# Radiobutton onCheckedChagned event

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Trying to implement a radiobutton `onCheckedChanged` event but code behind function isn't firing can someone point out to me what exactly i am doing wrong with the following code.

Aspx page

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"    AutoPostBack="true"   groupname="parent_category" id="rbCat1"  />
 <asp:RadioButton runat="server" checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"  AutoPostBack="true"   groupname="parent_category" id="rbCatCream"  />
```

Code Behind

```
  Public Sub Check_Clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    dim test as string =""
  end sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say it's **not firing**, do you mean on the initial post back by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <asp:RadioButton runat="server" checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"    AutoPostBack="true"   groupname="parent_category" id="rbCat1"  />
 <asp:RadioButton runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"  AutoPostBack="true"   groupname="parent_category" id="rbCatCream"  />


Protected Sub Check_Clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles rbCat1.CheckedChanged, rbCatCream.CheckedChanged
   dim test as string =""
end sub
```

Comment: Just tried that, but unfortunately didn't fix it, still not firing. I have it in a web user control, would that be why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdolist" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdolist_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="test" Value="test"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="test1" Value="test1"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>

// on code behind
Protected Sub rdolist_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdolist.SelectedIndexChanged
   // your code
end sub
```